# node 8.6 javascript promises: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am having an error: *(node:6186) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): threep
(node:6186) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.*
*-------- ones
========= two
CaughtCathchError threep
(node:6186) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 1)*
I am consuming my 3 promise functions in nested order.
p1,p2,p3- are my promise functions as shown below. 
i tried adding promise reject in all p1,p2,p3 functions as well but its still the same

```
enter code here
var p1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
       // resolve('ones')
                resolve('ones')
    }, 9000)
})
var p2 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        // throw new Error('eeeee');
        //reject('two')
    resolve('two')
    }, 1000)
})
var p3 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        reject('three')
    }, 4000)
})

p1.then(function(result){
    console.log("--------", result)
        // return p2.then(function(res){console.log(res)}).catch(function(err){console.log(err)})
        return p2
}).then(function(p2result){
    console.log("=========", p2result)
    return p3;
}).then(function(p3result){
    console.log('*********', p3result)
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("CaughtCathchError", err)
})
```

Comment: see that line `p3 = new Promise` etc ? you're not handling that rejection

Comment: This is basically a limitation in the unhandled rejection detection logic where it reports the unhandled rejection even though the rejection does end up in a `.catch()`.

Answer (score 3):

`p3` is a *standalone Promise* with no `.catch`. So, when `p3` gets `reject`ed, you get a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`. Even if `p3` is consumed *later* in a `Promise` chain that has a proper `catch`, `p3` itself does not have a `catch`.

Instead of `p3`, you might use a *function* that returns a `Promise`, and ensure that all calls to that function are caught:

```js
var p1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
       // resolve('ones')
                resolve('ones')
    }, 1000)
})
var p2 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        // throw new Error('eeeee');
        //reject('two')
    resolve('two')
    }, 1000)
})
var getp3 = () => new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        reject('three')
    }, 1000)
})

p1.then(function(result){
    console.log("--------", result)
        // return p2.then(function(res){console.log(res)}).catch(function(err){console.log(err)})
        return p2
}).then(function(p2result){
    console.log("=========", p2result)
    return getp3();
}).then(function(p3result){
    console.log('*********', p3result)
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("CaughtCathchError", err)
})
```

If you need to initialize `p3` immediately, then put a `catch` after the `p3` itself.

Comment: though, this means p3 wont START until p2 resolves - which may not be quite what the OP needs

Answer (score 2):

Node.js promise implementation expects rejected promise to be chained with `catch(...)` or `then(..., ...)` synchronously, otherwise `PromiseRejectionHandledWarning` appears. Unhandled promise rejections may result in exception in future.

Usually a rejection should be treated as any other error, so it's preferable for it to be an instance of `Error` and not plain string. Then it could be treated as such:

```
class ExpectedRejection extends Error {}

var p3 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        resolve(new ExpectedRejection('three'))
    }, 4000)
})

...
.then(function(p3result){
  if (p3result instanceof ExpectedRejection)
    throw p3result;

  console.log('*********', p3result)
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("CaughtCathchError", err)
})
```

`ExpectedRejection` class is specific and possibly not needed; could be replaced with `Error` everywhere because `Error` *resolutions* are uncommon.

This solution is not very common because if promises are created at the same time, they don't depend on each other and usually can be handled with `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all([p1, p2, p3])
.then(function(p1result, p2result, p3result){
    console.log('*********', p3result)
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("CaughtCathchError", err)
});
```

Notice that since `p1`, `p2` and `p3` are delays that are created at the same time, resulting `catch` will be triggered after 9 seconds (maximum duration of a delay) in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a rejecting/rejected promise that will be caught on the queue and not on the stack then you could do the following:

```
var p3 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        reject('three')
    }, 400)
});
//do not warn for p3 rejection but if you use it later (p3.then) or
//  return it in a promise chain you will have to catch it again
p3.catch(ignore=>ignore);
```