# Promises: is asynchronous handling OK?

Tags: node.js, promise

My question: Is it safe to detach the handling from its Promise object?

If I do this ...

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var json = { "counter":0 }
    console.log('execute now, worry later ...')
    json.counter++;
    console.log(json.counter)
    resolve(json);
});

var then = function() {
    promise1.then(function(value) { console.log('value: '+value.counter) });
} 

setTimeout(then, 3000);

var promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('error thrown here ...')
    throw new Error('will it behave the same as with then?');
});

var catchFunc = function() {
    promise2.then().catch(function(error) { console.log('error: '+error.message) });
} 

setTimeout(catchFunc, 3000);
```

Then I get warnings that make sense ...

```
execute now, worry later ...
1
error thrown here ...
(node:9748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: will it behave the same as with then?
(node:9748) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 1)
value: 1
error: will it behave the same as with then?
```

Background: In some cases, I want my promises to run concurrently. In some cases, I would like them to be run sequentially. The simplest implementation I've found is to wrap both variants into a function, push it in a map, and treat the "then / catch" in a reduce. The result is that my handling in the first variant (concurrently) is at the time of the wrapping and detached as in my sample above.

If it is safe, how can I remove the warnings from my log?

Comment: Hi Amadan, I assume your comment is a suggestion to get rid of the warnings. Catching without the then does not make a difference.

Comment: Misread, sorry. The problem is not in the fact they are separated in code, it's that they are separated in time. Can you show a real-world situation where you'd need to attach an error handler asynchronously?

Comment: This is the WRONG way to run async operations sequentially.  You should chain promises `fn().then(op1).then(op2)`.  Then, you have none of those issues.

Comment: What is the real problem here?  If you're just trying to run several async operations sequentially (so one completes before the next one starts), please edit your question to just say that.

Comment: I wonder who downvoted me. The only reason may be that I missed Estus post. My question shows reasearch effort, is useful and clear. Estus answered it and his answer is what I was aiming for. Others may benefit.

Comment: @otembajelle I don't think that anybody would downvote you because you didn't accept an answer instantly. That was a drive-by downvoter who fired at both answers and the question.

Comment: @estus my impulse yesterday was wrong you were right to downvote if it had been a suggestion. I appreciate your answer, it was very useful. I myself need to accept the way the rating mechanism at Stackoverflow is concipated. They do well because it is the best platform I know to exchange technical ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Rejected promise should be chained with `catch` on same tick. If this doesn't happen, `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` appears. It's expected to become an exception in next Node versions, so it's should be avoided.

Once promise control flow was introduced, it's beneficial to use promises. `setTimeout` stands out and doesn't provide error handling for promises.

If promises are processed concurrently, they are usually handled with `Promise.all(...).catch(...)`. In this case resulting promise is chained with `catch` on same tick (a similar problem is addressed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51113414/3731501)).

Comment: This is correct, but I'm not sure that it actually explains a solution to what the OP is really trying to do which appears to be to just run some async operations sequentially which is probably the better way to help.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'd like to give more precise answer, but the OP hasn't provided enough details yet, posted code looks more like 'I want my promises to run concurrently', though I suspect that the logic behind it is wrong.

Comment: @Estus thank you for your answer. Especially the information on the change in the next node versions is a big help.